# Copy Table from Local Sql Database to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

How can I go about copying a table from a local SQL database to an Azure SQL database nightly? Maybe I should use SSIS packages?

Comment: one more approach  with out using any technologies or spending time in configuration is to use Linked servers..

Answer (score 6):

Options (in rough order of preference):

- SQL Server Transactional Replication
- SSIS
- Azure Data Factory (especially for simple table copies)
- SQL Server Snapshot Replication
- Linked Server (INSERTs will be row-by-row)
- Azure Data Sync (still in preview)

Comment: No Data Factory with Gateway?

Comment: @wBob I Added it to the list.

Comment: lol thanks @DavidBrowne.  It seems like a decent candidate given Azure SQL DB is involved.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a good job for [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync#step-3---configure-sync-group).

I won't copy paste the article here, but the main steps are:

Step 1 - Create sync group
Step 2 - Add sync members
Step 3 - Configure sync group (here you can choose tables)

The link I've provided has the details

Answer (score 1):

i used SSIS was the quickest way in the end, doing a data task